# Increment address of access type as pointer in c using interface.c.pointer?

Tags: pointers, ada

Some unexpected behavior is noticed: `Put_Line(Integer'Image(Var.all)); var:=var+5;` -- it gives `1`,`var+6` then `2` and if `var+7` then 0,`var+8` then `-1`, can anyone please explain this?

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Interfaces.C.Pointers;
procedure Access_Pointer_Arithmetic is
   type Myarr_Indices is range 1 .. 5;
   type Myarr is array (Myarr_Indices range <>) of aliased Integer;
   Myarr_Terminator : constant Integer := 0;

   package Myarr_Pointer_Arithmetic is new Interfaces.C.Pointers
     (Myarr_Indices, Integer, Myarr, Myarr_Terminator);

   use Myarr_Pointer_Arithmetic;
   Myarr_Var : aliased Myarr := (2, 5, 7, 9, 0);
   Var : Myarr_Pointer_Arithmetic.Pointer :=Myarr_Var(Myarr_Var'First)'access;
begin
   Put_Line(Integer'Image(Var.all));
   var:=var+1;
   Put_Line(Integer'Image(Var.all));-- why 1?
   var:=var+8;
   Put_Line(Integer'Image(Var.all));-- why -1 and some time different 4-7 digits no?
end Access_Pointer_Arithmetic;
```

Comment: Please format your source text so it is possible to read it for others.  (Indentation is usually a good start.)

Comment: Your code does **not** give the answers you state. Here, it gives 2 OK), 5 (OK), then 2082407584, which is not OK. What did you *expect* would happen? How long is `Myarr_Var`? What is at `Myarr_Var(10)`?

Comment: @SimonWright please compile it twice thrice and run and keep on checking some time u will notice -1, and some time different no?

Comment: The second `Put_Line` always produces 5 for me. With regard to the third `Put_Line`: initially `var` designated the first element of `Myarr_Var`; then you increment it by 1, so it designates the second element; then you increment it by 8, so it designates the tenth element. **But `Myvar_Arr` only has 5 elements!** So I say again, what did you *expect* would happen?

Comment: @SimonWright just i am unable to figure out it why i am getting like this if i am make incrementing more than its range ? i was think it should give 0 as in case of c partially initialized value become 0 ? so please can u explain why i am getting so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ada code is precisely equivalent to this C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int arr[5] = {2, 5, 7, 9, 0};
  int *p = arr;
  printf("%d\n", *p);
  p += 1;
  printf("%d\n", *p);
  p += 8;
  printf("%d\n", *p);
  return 0;
}
```

which, when it’s run, produces (on my machine)

```
2
5
32767
```

You have told the compiler to reserve space for 5 `int`s (20 bytes), in which you have put some data. The compiler is free to use the space beyond the end of the array for whatever it likes; it certainly doesn’t belong to you, you have no idea what it’s used for: HANDS OFF!

So when you increment the pointer to what would be the tenth element of the array if you had declared it to be at least 10 elements long, you are addressing undefined data. You have no reason to suppose that it’s an `int`; it might be part of a character string, it might be the middle of a `double`, it might be anything. On a desktop machine, it’s unlikely to be a memory location which will cause the machine to catch fire when it’s read; a bit less unlikely in a microcontroller running your toaster.

Writing via the pointer is almost guaranteed to make your program crash, immediately or thousands of instructions later when you will have real trouble finding the bug.

The Ada word for this behaviour of a program is “erroneous”; the C word is, I believe, “undefined”.